# How to fix a problem with angularjs on Safari?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari

I am trying to download a file, in Google Chrome it works without a problem but in SAFARI the following error is displayed:

'undefined' anchor.attr({'...'})[0].click() is not a function.

```
anchor.css({display: 'none'});
angular.element(document.body).append(anchor);
// Safari and others
anchor.attr({href: 'data:application/pdf,' + encodeURIComponent(vm.pdfF), download: 'File_' + vm.number + '.pdf'})[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURIComponent(vm.pdfF), '_blank');
```